# Control to get back from Eventhandler to original location in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In a method i called an event handler say **MyButton.PerformClick()**. At runtime, After executing the functionality of  button click **MyButton_CLick(object Sender, EventArgs e)**, the execution pointer is not come back to the Event calling point location to perform execution in the method down-line. 
Is there a way to return the control from event handler to the method calling point?

Provide me with code in C#.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: If the execution doesn't return to the point right after PerformClick() then it sounds like there may have been an exception in your handler.

Answer (score 1):

They way events work, the only way you can achieve what you want is by calling  event handler directly (which is not a good practice!)

```
MyButton_CLick(null, EventArgs.Empty)
```

instead of

```
 MyButton.PerformClick()
```

Comment: I'm passing a value to this event handler. **myButton.Tag = "something";**

How can i achieve this??

Comment: can you post some code around what you are trying to do? I'm a little confused as to what your objective is.

Comment: `Public void Open()
{
   foreach(string item in ItemsArray)
   {
      switch(choice)
       {
        case "Box":
              Button_CLick(null,EventArgs.Empty);
              string s = "this is next execution statement after the above event" ;
              continue;
        case "Tools":
                  //.....
              continue;
        default:
              break;
        }          
  
    }
}`

Comment: After execution of Button_CLick(), the control is not coming back to next statement.